# Android drawing a path ON TOP of another path

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, hashmap

So I am facing this weird problem in my drawing app.

I drew these lines from 1 to 8 from top to bottom and from left to right.

[image]

While I'm drawing the line, it shows as it's drawing Behind all the other lines. Whenever I let go off the screen, it **sometimes** pops up front, this seems completely random.

What am I overlooking to draw on top of everything else at all times?

My DrawView.java:

```java
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    private Map<Path, Paint> pathMap = new HashMap<Path, Paint>();

    private boolean isScreenCleared = false;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (isScreenCleared) {
            pathMap.clear();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            isScreenCleared = false;
        } else {
            //Current line
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

            //All other lines
            for (Map.Entry<Path, Paint> p : pathMap.entrySet()) {
                canvas.drawPath(p.getKey(), p.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path = new Path();
            path.reset();
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Paint newPaint = new Paint();
            newPaint.set(paint);
            pathMap.put(path, newPaint);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return paint.getStrokeWidth();
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(radius);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        System.out.println("Color set to: " + color);
    }

    public void clearScreen() {
        isScreenCleared = true;
        invalidate();
    }   
}
```

I am instantiating DrawView in my MainActivity like this:

```java
Relative layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawscreen);

DrawView dv = new DrawView(layout.getContext());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem thanks to Spartygw but found something better than `Vector`s.

There is a `LinkedHashMap` that IS deterministic.

So using that solves the problem.

**Also:**

It painting behind everything else **while** drawing was a quick mistake on my end as I obviously need to draw the current line **after** the whole (Linked)HashMap.

Comment: Unless you are doing something that you haven't shown, using a LinkedHashMap is not the best container choice.  It's a heavier container than Vector or List or...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a HashMap to store the paths.  Use a Vector and add new paths to the end.  Then as you draw them and iterate through your vector you will draw them in the right order with the most recent on top.

From HashMap docs:

```
Note that the iteration order for HashMap is non-deterministic.
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the problem! I posted the answer which uses a LinkedHashMap instead of a Vector.

Comment: Do I get an accepted answer out of it?  I need some points! :)